# Join on range query using Esri's GIS Tools for Hadoop?

Tags: spatial-framework-hadoop, gis-tools-hadoop

I am getting myself acquainted with Esri's [GIS Tools for Hadoop](https://github.com/Esri/gis-tools-for-hadoop). Working with Hive.

One of my tables, A, has user lat-lons. Another, B, has landmarks and their lat-lons. How do I join two tables so that I get all landmarks names and their locations from B within a given distance (radius) from each location in A? How to replicate a k-NN query, if possible?

Can I do it with Esri's GIS Tools for Hadoop?

I have heard of Hadoop GIS and SpatialHadoop, but there are limitations - cannot get them working.

Answer (score 1):

For distance join, try [ST_GeodesicLengthWGS84](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/wiki/UDF-Accessors#st_geodesiclengthwgs84), as also discussed in [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/issues/53).

[More samples of ST_GeodesicLengthWGS84 can be found in this test script](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/blob/master/hive/test/st-geom-text.sql).

For selecting attributes with a spatial join, see the [point-in-polygon sample in GIS Tools for Haoop](https://github.com/Esri/gis-tools-for-hadoop/tree/master/samples/point-in-polygon-aggregation-hive).

For kNN, can you accept an upper bound on the distance?  If so, distance query + `order by` + `limit`.

[Disclosure: collaborator.]